# What is the $n^{th}$ term derivative of $f(x) = (x^2-x-1)(\ln(1-x))$?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

**I have the first three terms but am struggling with finding the $n^{th}$ term derivative of the function. Here is my work:**

$$\\$$
$$f(x) = (x^2-x-1)(\ln(1-x)) $$
$$f'(x) = (2x-1)(\ln(1-x))-\left(\dfrac{x^2-x-1}{1-x}\right)$$
$$f''(x) = \dfrac{3x^2-5x+2(x-1)^2 \ln(1-x)+3}{(1-x)^2}$$
$$f'''(x) = \dfrac{2x^2-5x+1}{(x-1)^3}$$
$$f^{(n)}(x) = \ ?$$

Comment: What happened to ln in f"'?

Comment: @William Elliot: If you separate the log term from the fraction expression for $f''$, the factor of $(x - 1)^2$ cancels, and taking the derivative (for the third time) makes the expression rational.

Answer (score 6):

Use the following.
$$f'''(x)=\frac{2x^2-5x+1}{(x-1)^3}=\frac{2x^2-4x+2-x+1-2}{(x-1)^3}=\frac{2}{x-1}-\frac{1}{(x-1)^2}-\frac{2}{(x-1)^3}.$$
Can you end it now?

Answer (score 0):

As you noticed,
$$
f^{(3)}(x)=\frac{2x^{2}-5x+1}{\left(x-1\right)^{3}}.
$$
[Wolfram](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=D%5B(1%20-%205%20x%20%2B%202%20x%5E2)%2F(-1%20%2B%20x)%5E3,%7Bx,n%7D%5D) claims that
$$
f^{(3+n)}(x)=n!\frac{n^{2}+n\left(x+2\right)-2x^{2}+5x-1}{\left(x-1\right)^{3+n}}.
$$
To convince yourself that this is indeed the case, fix $n\geq0$ and differentiate the expression for $f^{(3+n)}$ to get the expression for $f^{(3+n+1)}$.

Comment: Thank you for the advice, this helped out a lot.

Answer (score 0):

It might be useful here to make a small substitution and to expand the parentheses:

- $y = 1-x \Rightarrow y' = -1$
- $\Rightarrow f(x) = g(y(x)) = -(1+x(1-x))\ln (1-x) = -(1+(1-y)y)\ln y$

Now differentiate $\boxed{g(y) = -\ln y - y\ln y + y^2 \ln y}$ with respect to $x$ and have in mind that $\color{blue}{y'(x) = -1}$ (which leads to the changing signs below):
\begin{eqnarray*}
f'(x) & = & \frac{1}{y} + (\ln y + 1) - (2y\ln y + y) \\
f''(x) & = & \frac{1}{y^2} - \frac{1}{y} + (2\ln y + 2) +1 \\
f^{(3)}(x) & = & \frac{2}{y^3} - \frac{1}{y^2} - \frac{2}{y}\\
 & \ldots & \\
f^{(n)} & = & \ldots \\
\end{eqnarray*}
For example replacing $y = 1-x$ gives $f^{(3)}(x) = \frac{2}{(1-x)^3} - \frac{1}{(1-x)^2} - \frac{2}{1-x}$.